# Optional time_select with allow_blank defaults to 00:00

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a time field in my form optional. I'm doing this:

```
<%= f.time_select :end_time, minute_step: 5, include_blank: true %>
```

However when it is submitted, since there is default date information being submitted automatically with time_select, this is what the params looks like:

`end_time(1i): '2000'
  end_time(2i): '1'
  end_time(3i): '1'
  end_time(4i): ''
  end_time(5i): ''`

Rails interprets this as a real date and sets end_time to 00:00

Is there any fix/workout to be able to have an optional time field? I tried this in the controller:

```
if params[:event][:end_time] && params[:event][:end_time][:hour].blank? && params[:event][:end_time][:minute].blank?
  params[:event][:end_time] = nil
end
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your param is not [:event][:end_time], they are:

[:event]['end_time(1i)']..[:event]['end_time(5i)'] respectively.

Making the param value nil won't help, you need to reject that key from your params hash; e.g.

`params[:event].except('end_time(4i)', 'end_time(5i)') if params[:event]['end_time(4i)'].blank?`

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. If I .except the end_time, then it won't update the record to blank values if it already had a time value in it. Any way to set it to nil somehow instead?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. Thanks again! Loading the attributes, then doing before the save: @event.end_time = nil if params[:event]['end_time(4i)'].blank?

Answer (score 6):

Following along the same lines, something that worked well for me was this:

Add a before filter/action to the controller

```
before_filter :filter_blank_end_time, only: [:create, :update]
```

Create the filter

```
def filter_blank_end_time
    if params[:event]['end_time(4i)'].blank?
        params[:event]['end_time(1i)'] = ""
        params[:event]['end_time(2i)'] = ""
        params[:event]['end_time(3i)'] = ""
        params[:event]['end_time(4i)'] = ""
        params[:event]['end_time(5i)'] = ""
    end
end
```

Passing in empty stings for all fields seem to yield a NIL value for end time.

Comment: I had a similar problem when submitting blank/nil time.  Your above solution works but I had to check `blank?` on `(5i)` as that's how my time field was being stored, not in the `(4i)` params.  Thanks for the tip!