# Rails: How not to save value with using time_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add `time_select` with `include_blank`. I'm doing this:

```
    <%= f.time_select :start_at, include_blank: true, ampm: true %><br>
```

What I'd like to do is to delete value (save nil?) if blank is selected in view.

Although I tried the following posts, it didn't work for me.

[time_select blank field saves a default time when form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367705/time-select-blank-field-saves-a-default-time-when-form-is-submitted)

[Optional time_select with allow_blank defaults to 00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851659/optional-time-select-with-allow-blank-defaults-to-0000)

1) When I try as below, no error is appeared, but `00:00:00` is saved.

**controller**

```
  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if event_params["start_at(4i)"].blank? or event_params["start_at(5i)"].blank?
      @event.start_at = nil
    end

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:success] = "event updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

2) When I try as below (change if clause), no error is appeared, but `00:00:00` is saved.

**controller**

```
  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if params[:id]["start_at(4i)"].blank? or params[:id]["start_at(5i)"].blank?
      @event.start_at = nil
    end

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:success] = "event updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

3) When I try as below (add before_action), no error is appeared, but `00:00:00` is saved.

**controller**

```
  before_action :blank_time,     only: [:update]

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:success] = "event updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def blank_time
      if params[:id]["start_at(4i)"].blank? or params[:id]["start_at(5i)"].blank?
        params[:id]['start_at(1i)'] = ""
        params[:id]["start_at(2i)"] = ""
        params[:id]["start_at(3i)"] = ""
        params[:id]["start_at(4i)"] = ""
        params[:id]["start_at(5i)"] = ""
      end
    end
```

4) When I try as below (use `nil` instead of `""`), error is appeared.

**error**

```
IndexError (string not matched):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:106:in `[]='
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:106:in `blank_time'
```

**controller**

```
  before_action :blank_time,     only: [:update]

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:success] = "event updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def blank_time
      if params[:id]["start_at(4i)"].blank? or params[:id]["start_at(5i)"].blank?
        params[:id]['start_at(1i)'] = nil
        params[:id]["start_at(2i)"] = nil
        params[:id]["start_at(3i)"] = nil
        params[:id]["start_at(4i)"] = nil
        params[:id]["start_at(5i)"] = nil
      end
    end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

**UPDATE**

Although I change the edit in `events_controller.rb` as below, the error `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute 'start_at(4i)'):` is displayed.

```
  def edit
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    @event = @room.events.find(params[:id])

    @event['start_at(4i)'] = @event.start_at.split(':')[0]   #the error occur here
    @event['start_at(5i)'] = @event.start_at.split(':')[1]
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

**My idea works like this:**

***Migration:***

```
class CreateTests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :tests do |t|
  t.string :time

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

***Form:***

```
<%= form_for(test) do |f| %>
<% if test.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(test.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this test from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% test.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :time %>
<%= f.time_select :time, include_blank: true, ampm: false %><br>
</div>

<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

***Controller:***
This will save : when value send are null where you can use conditional to check if parameters are null or and set value of time. //It's consuming much time and I skipped for you to complete.

```
def create
@test = Test.new(test_params)
@time = (params[:test]['time(4i)']).to_s
@time_ampm = (params[:test]['time(5i)']).to_s
@test.time = @time+":"+ @time_ampm

respond_to do |format|
  if @test.save
    format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @test }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

**For updating**

```
def edit
 @test = Test.find(params[:id])
 @test['time(4i)'] = @test.time.split(':')[0]
 @test['time(5i)'] = @test.time.split(':')[1]
end

def update
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  @time = (params[:test]['time(4i)']).to_s
  @time_ampm = (params[:test]['time(5i)']).to_s
  @test.time = @time+":"+ @time_ampm
  @test.update(test_params)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Pradeep Sapkota. The value saved in database is `00:00:00` not `null`. I'd like to know how to save `null` when I select blank at `time_select`.

Comment: if you want null as a default value you better to store it in a string.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue Which database type are you using?

Comment: @Owen I think this is not database type issue. It's data type issue

Comment: @PradeepSapkota True but it might help answer succinctly. SamuraiBlue should create a new migration that will remove the default value and allow `NULL` instead of changing to a string.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Owen and @Pradeep Sapkota. The data type is `time`. I use postgresql. Although I consider the possibility that `time` type doesn't accept `NULL`, I can save `NULL`  when I try to `UPDATE` null directly to database with SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Owen and @Pradeep Sapkota. I try to use `time_select` to string field. For example, when I select `8AM` and `12`, `{1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>8, 5=>12}` is saved in database. How can I display this time on view when I want edit with `time_select`? Although it may be another question, it would be appreciated if you could give me a clue.

Comment: I have posted complete solution now. That's what I know. See Answer Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your update, @Pradeep Sapkota. It would be appreciated if you could give me how to `update` the value to `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for your updating, @Pradeep Sapkota. The error `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute 'time(4i)')` is displayed when I try to edit. This occur at `@test['time(4i)'] = @test.time.split(':')[0]` in `edit`. It would be appreciated if you could give me advice.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `@event.starts_at` to nil does nothing as the attributes in `#event_params` is used when calling `#update`,  overwriting your initial assignment.

Overwriting the starts_at attribute in your params should work instead.

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if event_params["start_at(4i)"].blank? or event_params["start_at(5i)"].blank?
      event_params = event_params.reject { |k, v| k.starts_with? 'starts_at' }
                                 .merge(starts_at: nil)
    end

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:success] = "event updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

The following line finds and remove the parameters for `starts_at(1i)` to `starts_at(5i)`, then sets the whole `starts_at` attribute  to be nil:

`event_params.reject { |k, v| k.starts_with? 'starts_at' }.merge(starts_at: nil)`

Comment: Thank you for quick response, @Ivan. Altｈough I'm not yet inadequately understood your answer, the following error is displayed when I try. `NoMethodError (undefined method ’reject' for nil:NilClass):`. And is that correct to add your code in `def update` ?

Comment: Yes, you should remove your before_action and add it to the update method (in the if blank clause of your first example).

Comment: Thank you for your comment and editing your answer, @Ivan. Although I tried your answer, same error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'reject' for nil:NilClass):` is still displayed.